# Grep strange exclusion of empty lines from the output

Tags: grep, regular-expression

When solving common tasks filtering of comments, e.g. I can do so:

```
grep -v ^# /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Such way I got not commented and empty lines. That was expected.

I thought that another way is:

```
grep ^[^#] /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

However I got the same output but without empty lines. What is the reason?

Comment: @hildred @steeldriver From some testing in perl I saw that inside perl-script our "empty lines" (with only one newline) had length 1. But when I check file through perl one-liner like `perl -lane 'print length' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` "empty lines" had zero length (the same as in grep). But it is not entirely clear for me.

Comment: In Perl the length of the string may include a newline (if it is there it is counted) but the regex engine ignores trailing newlines unless you explicitly enable newline matching. This was done to have better compatibility with sed and awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is looking for lines with at least one character and therefore does not match empty lines which have no  characters. If you want both  try the following:

```
grep -e ^[^#] -e ^$ /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v ^#
```

- exclude lines that do not start with `#`
- blank lines do not start with `#`, so are not **ex**cluded

wheras

```
grep ^[^#]
```

- include lines that start with any character except `#`
- blank lines do not start with *any* character, so are not **in**cluded